# C# fail to create file in directory if has other file

Tags: c#, parsing, getfiles

Can someone help me, I just learning C# for about 2 month, I have this problem,
i'm building a class for filter data from temp file and create the result in new txt file inside directory, if directory is empty nor at the same date, it build perfectly, and if there another file at same date it should create with increase the last number at lastname.

My problem when I run code, it is not creating if the directory has files with the same dates,  then the result should be something like this:

- C:\result_2014051301.txt
- C:\result_2014051401.txt
- C:\result_2014051402.txt  <-- Failed, it is not ..2014051401.txt

  ```
   class Entity2
   {
      public Entity2()
      {
         string fileTemp = "DEFAULT.temp";
         string indexD = Properties.Settings.Default.ChIndex2D;
         string indexC = Properties.Settings.Default.ChIndex2C;
         string indexS = Properties.Settings.Default.ChIndex2S;
         string tempPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
         string targetPath = Properties.Settings.Default.ExtractALL_DIR;
         string SourceFile = Path.Combine(tempPath, fileTemp);
         string tempFileX = Path.GetTempFileName();

         if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
         {
             System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error missing .temp", "Message Box");
         }
         else
         {
             string ext = ".txt";
             int sequence = 0;
             DateTime dateFileName = DateTime.Today;
             string discode = Properties.Settings.Default.ChannelID_2;
             string filename = discode + "_" + dateFileName.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
             string pathX = Properties.Settings.Default.ExtractALL_DIR + @"/Channel2";

             if (!Directory.Exists(pathX))
             {
                 Directory.CreateDirectory(pathX);
             }

             string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(pathX, filename + "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
             if (files.Length > 0)
             {
                 Array.Sort(files);
                 string lastFilename = files[files.Length - 1];
                 sequence = Int32.Parse(lastFilename.Substring(0, lastFilename.Length - 4).Replace(pathX + filename, ""));

             }

             sequence++;

             string newFileName = filename + sequence.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + ext;
             string DestFile = Path.Combine(pathX, newFileName);

             using (var ab = new StreamReader(SourceFile))
             using (var cd = new StreamWriter(DestFile))
             {
                string lineX;

                while ((lineX = ab.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                  if (lineX.LastIndexOf("100", 3) != -1 || lineX.LastIndexOf("MGR", 15) != -1 || lineX.LastIndexOf(indexC, 15) != -1)
                  {
                      lineX = lineX.Replace(indexD, "");
                      lineX = lineX.Replace("DEFAULT", discode);
                      if (lineX.LastIndexOf("800", 3) != -1)
                      {
                          lineX = lineX.Replace(indexS, "");
                      }
                      cd.WriteLine(lineX);
                  }

                }
             }
         }
      }
   }
  ```

Comment: Be sure to include any exceptions that occur when your application fails, they are very helpful in finding the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This piece is not functioning correctly:

```
Int32.Parse(lastFilename.Substring(0, lastFilename.Length - 4).Replace(pathX + filename, ""));
```

`pathX + filename` is `C:\folderfile.txt` not `C:\folder\file.txt`.

You either need to add the `\` or call `Path.Join`.

That will cause the `Parse` operation to fail since it tries to consume the who string (minus the extension).

Comment: @user3641945: What help do you want?

Comment: @user3641945: I don't fix code for strangers on the internet for free. I will help you learn but not solve your problem. Hell the last time I solved someones problem they deleted the thread on me.

Comment: @Guvante The good news is only moderators can delete threads with an existing answer!

Comment: @tnw: Good to hear, was a long long time ago :)

Comment: @user3641945 a good way of showing gratitude on an answer is to accept it. :)